# max , min average of input stream

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am given an input stream &  two indexes (i & j) between which you need to calculate the min, max & avg of all the numbers. Which data structure should I you use & how should I calculate the values?

Comment: Seems fairly straightforward. Have you tried to solve it yourself? Can we see your attempt?

Comment: That would be interesting if there were a ton of index-pairs. Prefix sums and RMQ, nice. For one pair of indexes it's absolutely trivial though.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any data structure would be fine here- depending on language of course.  Depending on the language, a list would probably be quickest to implement.  Calculating min, max, and average are pretty simple- iterate through your values.  Take each value and compare it to your current min and max values- if it is higher than the max or lower than the min, replace that, and then add the value to a running total for average purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for this would be to use simple arrays.

Array 1: Input you just store the input at the next index.

Array 2: Sum: sum[i] = input[1](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree) + input[2] + ... + input[i]

This allows avg quickly. O(1) but min and max in the worst case is still O(N).

If you want something else, you can use a [segment tree](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Segment_tree) and do all of the queries in O(log n) time. Insert also becomes O(log n)